# What is the best way to connect two monitors to a macbook pro?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook

What is the best way to connect two monitors to a macbook pro?

Is there hardware to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind spending some money you could always buy a [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/)

> Matrox DualHead2Go is an external multi-monitor upgrade that adds up to two monitors to your notebook or desktop computer. Ideal for business and professional users looking to increase their productivity with a dual monitor setup, this small box lets you run different applications on each monitor or view one application across two monitors. DualHead2Go is available in DisplayPort, Digital, or Analog Editions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what iteration of MBP you have, but I would try 1 over DVI, the other over DisplayPort if you have both of those connectors.